# Unable to link html with JS file

Tags: javascript, html, css, static-linking

That's my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="ll.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
        
        <h1><span>Styled</span> and <span>filterable</span> select dropdown</h1>

        <form>
            <input class="chosen-value" type="text" value="" placeholder="Type to filter">
            <ul class="value-list">
              <li>Alabama</li>
              <li>Alaska</li>
              <li>Arizona</li>
              <li>Arkansas</li>
              <li>California</li>
              <li>Colorado</li>
              <li>Connecticut</li>
              <li>Delaware</li>
              <li>Florida</li>
              <li>Georgia</li>
              <li>Hawaii</li>
              <li>Idaho</li>
              <li>Illinois</li>
              <li>Indiana</li>
              <li>Iowa</li>
              <li>Kansas</li>
              <li>Kentucky</li>
              <li>Louisiana</li>
              <li>Maine</li>
              <li>Maryland</li>
              <li>Massachusetts</li>
              <li>Michigan</li>
              <li>Minnesota</li>
              <li>Mississippi</li>
              <li>Missouri</li>
              <li>Montana</li>
              <li>Nebraska</li>
              <li>Nevada</li>
              <li>New Hampshire</li>
              <li>New Jersey</li>
              <li>New Mexico</li>
              <li>New York</li>
              <li>North Carolina</li>
              <li>North Dakota</li>
            </ul>
          </form>


</body>
</html>
```

My CSS is linked properly.
JavaScript file (ll.js):

```
const inputField = document.querySelector('.chosen-value');
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.value-list');
const dropdownArray = [... document.querySelectorAll('li')];
console.log(typeof dropdownArray)
dropdown.classList.add('open');
inputField.focus(); // Demo purposes only
let valueArray = [];
dropdownArray.forEach(item => {
  valueArray.push(item.textContent);
});

const closeDropdown = () => {
  dropdown.classList.remove('open');
}

inputField.addEventListener('input', () => {
  dropdown.classList.add('open');
  let inputValue = inputField.value.toLowerCase();
  let valueSubstring;
  if (inputValue.length > 0) {
    for (let j = 0; j < valueArray.length; j++) {
      if (!(inputValue.substring(0, inputValue.length) === valueArray[j].substring(0, inputValue.length).toLowerCase())) {
        dropdownArray[j].classList.add('closed');
      } else {
        dropdownArray[j].classList.remove('closed');
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < dropdownArray.length; i++) {
      dropdownArray[i].classList.remove('closed');
    }
  }
});

dropdownArray.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    inputField.value = item.textContent;
    dropdownArray.forEach(dropdown => {
      dropdown.classList.add('closed');
    });
  });
})

inputField.addEventListener('focus', () => {
   inputField.placeholder = 'Type to filter';
   dropdown.classList.add('open');
   dropdownArray.forEach(dropdown => {
     dropdown.classList.remove('closed');
   });
});

inputField.addEventListener('blur', () => {
   inputField.placeholder = 'Select state';
  dropdown.classList.remove('open');
});

document.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  const isDropdown = dropdown.contains(evt.target);
  const isInput = inputField.contains(evt.target);
  if (!isDropdown && !isInput) {
    dropdown.classList.remove('open');
  }
});
```

How can I link they properly? I have tried adding

```
        <script src="ll.js"></script>
```

at multiple other places like in form tag, in body tag but it doesn't work. I tested JS, HTML and CSS on JsBin it works perfectly just the problem is in linking these files together.

Comment: Did you try at the end of the body? (just above `</body>`?

Comment: render blocking things must be added at the end of body tag. You need to try adding <script /> tag at the end of body tag and add link tag in head tag and if this doesn't solve the issue then it's mostly due to path problem.

Comment: Thanks it worked, placing just before: </body>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can ,

```
Add after `<body> ..</body><script>...` ends. or 

<script src='ll.js' defer></script>
```

So basically, you need to `defer` the execution of your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Call `javascript` file before `body` tag that will solve your problem
and you should change name from `11.js` to `main.js` or something else that's will be much better

your file will be like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>


    </head>
    <body>
        
        <h1><span>Styled</span> and <span>filterable</span> select dropdown</h1>

        <form>
            <input class="chosen-value" type="text" value="" placeholder="Type to filter">
            <ul class="value-list">
              <li>Alabama</li>
              <li>Alaska</li>
              <li>Arizona</li>
              <li>Arkansas</li>
              <li>California</li>
              <li>Colorado</li>
              <li>Connecticut</li>
              <li>Delaware</li>
              <li>Florida</li>
              <li>Georgia</li>
              <li>Hawaii</li>
              <li>Idaho</li>
              <li>Illinois</li>
              <li>Indiana</li>
              <li>Iowa</li>
              <li>Kansas</li>
              <li>Kentucky</li>
              <li>Louisiana</li>
              <li>Maine</li>
              <li>Maryland</li>
              <li>Massachusetts</li>
              <li>Michigan</li>
              <li>Minnesota</li>
              <li>Mississippi</li>
              <li>Missouri</li>
              <li>Montana</li>
              <li>Nebraska</li>
              <li>Nevada</li>
              <li>New Hampshire</li>
              <li>New Jersey</li>
              <li>New Mexico</li>
              <li>New York</li>
              <li>North Carolina</li>
              <li>North Dakota</li>
            </ul>
          </form>

          <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your JS code is attempting to query the document to target some elements. So the script should run after the document is parsed.

Linking your JS file at the end of the body solved the issue. You could also have used the `DOMContentLoaded` event... So the script would execute after all elements are present:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // Your script
})
```

And then, you can link your JS file in the head of the document.